# did I use the colon correctly?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I am trying to use this statement but am unsure if I am using the colon correctly. I am trying to write

" He quotes one of Job’s religious sayings, it being: "

(context: this is to introduce the fact that Benjamin Banneker is quoting Job, a man from the bible.)

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it. Personally, I would remove *, it being* and put the colon directly after *sayings*. But that's just a stylistic choice.

Comment: I'm unsure whether (not "if").

Answer (score 1):

Using a colon for one-list item (restatement or emphasis) is standard practice.

Furthermore, if in the original text it does not appear with quotes, then adding quotes and substituting a comma for the colon is as acceptable, if not more so, especially considering that you're... quoting a quote (seems fitting to put it in quotes :3).

Agree with @jason to remove *it being*, in any case.